# base64 string is not uploaded in server android?

Tags: android, base64, android-image, android-gallery

I need to send the image (from gallery)  to server in the format of base64 string. I get the path of the image and converted it to base64 string. but at server the image is not showing fully. only 10% of the image is showing at server side.Please any one help me how to convert the image to base64 string.

code:

```
filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);    

Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmapOrg.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bao);
byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
ba1 =Base64.encodeToString(ba, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

image size:460kb

Answer (score 0):

try with this i hope it will work for you and send using httpPost method.

public static String BitmapToString(Bitmap bmp) {

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
return base64;
}
```

and server side.

Base64 base64=new Base64();
saveImage(base64.decode(profilePic),"yourName");

```
public void saveImage(byte[] bytes,String name){

    String path="D:/"+name.hashCode()+".png";
 try {
        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(path);
        f.write(bytes);
        f.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
    }



 }
```

Comment: send using httpPost method.

Comment: @vikas..i dont know about server side code(.net service).i simply send the code and checking at server side without sendinng with http post. shall i send with http post ?

Comment: @androidandroid use httpPost client b,coz httpGet have limitation so you can not send large data. ex- HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post=new HttpPost("your-Url");

Comment: after getting the file path i converted it to base64string and get the code. after that i send the code to server person and checking it....not using service